# Shadow artifacts in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, artifacts

[image]

As visible in the image, the render is showing artifacts near close edges. Cycles is not showing any such problem.

Now, I am planning on adding a lightsabre in the scene and would like to render it in Eevee, for the Bloom. So, how to remove these artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Render Properties, under Shadow, you can pump up Cube Size to attenuate those artifacts.

Also, those artifacts may appear in the Viewport, but be less visible while Rendered. This is beacause Viewport and Render don't necessarily have the same Sampling (in Render Properties / Sampling).